# How can I manage large input to my RSS endpoint?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, rss

I have an Angular + ASP.Net WebAPI Application. I am posting a JSON query to an 
API and in return getting the RSS formatted feed.

```
$scope.rss = function(query){
    $http.post("api/url", query)
        .success(function(response){
             //I have RSS feed (xml string) in response
             //But cannot publish it as RSS
             /*response = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                 <rss version="2.0">
                     <channel>
                         ...
                     </channel>
                 </rss>"*/
         })
         .error(function(e){
             //error
        });
}
```

Now, my API accepts HttpPost, and I cannot use HttpGet because, the query can get really big. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: title of your question and details does not match. Looks like you want to "How can I manage large input to my RSS endpoint?" - If that is what you are looking for please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if I'm correct, you're trying to get the Angular application to "render" the RSS feed content it gets from the backend, right?

The quick answer is that you can't do this directly *inside* the angular application, because of course, your Angular app is tied to the DOM (or at least to JS scripts), which will be wiped if you render RSS.

What you can do, though is generate a `data-uri` with the content of the RSS feed and then, redirect (or open a new tab) to this data-uri.